# What are the steps required to use JW Player 7.22?

Tags: jwplayer, video-player, jwplayer7

My client has purchased the premium version of JW Palyer 7.2 for the his video streaming website.

He was given the key "GGKKXXXXXXXXXXXXBBXX887VV".

How do I use that to play the live video streaming.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully that's not his real key, but assuming his key is a string of characters with an equals sign, instantiation would look like this for JW Player 7.

```
<script src="//mywebsite.com/jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>
<script>jwplayer.key="ABCdeFG123456SeVenABCdeFG123456SeVen==";</script>

<div id="thePlayer"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

jwplayer("thePlayer").setup({
    file: "file.mp4",
    width:640,
    height:360
});

</script>
```

If you're trying to stream video, then you will most likely need a few more parameters, such as buffer.